# find duplicated class within div using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="d">
    <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
    <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
    <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
    <p class="head"></p>
    <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
    <p class="head"></p>
</div>
```

I have few block of '.d' , how to use each() to find whether '.head' is more than one? if yes, remove the duplicated '.head'

```
$('.d').each(function(index, value){
// find duplicated .head
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.not()` function along with `:eq()` selector to achieve what you want,

```
$('.d').each(function(){
 $(".head",this).not(":eq(0)").remove();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v4ea47yq/)

Comment: eq(0) is to select the first head right? but why use with not() ?

Comment: @JamesLemon For excluding it.

Comment: if I want to check is the parant contain more than 2 items?

Comment: @JamesLemon Then use `.filter(':gt(1)')` instead of  `.not(":eq(0)")`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `.each`, just use a selector that matches all the duplicates after the first one.

```
$(".d .head:not(:nth-child(0))").remove();
```

Comment: The indexing of nth-child starts with one! `$(".d .head:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();` is correct. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Straight away you can do it in a single statement as:

```
$('.d').find(".head:gt(0)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :first-child

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(".d .head:not(:first-child)").remove();
})
```

```css
.d {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.d .head {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d">
  <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
  <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
  <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
  <p class="head"></p>
  <p class="head"></p>
</div>

<div class="d">
  <p class="head"></p>
</div>
<button>Remove</button>
```